# NSURLSession returns data with bad access code

Tags: swift, http, asynchronous, nsurlsession

This function is returning a nil value for the data variable for some reason and I can't understand why. I have already searched through many posts and can't seem to find a difference. I had this working already with a request using different data but if I cURL the responses they are identical. It only makes it as far as the line that states:

`if let JSONData = responseString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {`

and never goes into that if because the `responseString` value was never set. Changing it to be implicit like

`if let JSONData = responseString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {`

returns a bad access code.

```
func getData(url: String, dataToSend: String, username: String, password: String) {

    someVar = [MyObjectType]()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "%URLTOUSE%")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "%POSTDATAHERE%"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        dump(responseString)
        if let JSONData = responseString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            if var jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
                if var jsonInfo = jsonDict["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if var jsonInfoSub = jsonInfo["data"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                        for report in jsonInfoSub {
                            self.someVar.append(MyObjectType(json: report))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

All help appreciated!

**EDIT: Additional Information**

this is the dump output for the other variables

dumping `data` returns a bad access code

```
response: - <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fbc5aca7120> { URL: ____ } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 428205;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    Date = "Fri, 29 May 2015 17:11:04 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=3, max=100";
    P3P = "CP=\"NOI DEVa TAIa OUR BUS UNI STA\"";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "_____; expires=Sat, 28-May-2016 17:11:04 GMT; HttpOnly, _____=76b17d064b58c412d078b5430ca9367e; HttpOnly";
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
    "X-Robots-Tag" = "noindex, nofollow";
} } #0
```

error returns: `- nil`

Comment: So, you get data, transform it into an NSString, then transform this string into data... Inspect the `data` you get from `dataTaskWithRequest`, then if not nil, use it directly for the NSJSONSerialization instead (skip the NSString part). Also, use the available error variables, don't ignore them. You should debug a bit, inspecting your data to find *where* it becomes nil.

Comment: @EricD. I just updated the question with more info.

Comment: Response has `"Content-Type" = "text/html`, but you treat its data as JSON... Looks like there's a problem here.

Comment: @EricD. I checked if the other url that I tried (which works correctly) has a different `Content-Type` but it's also `text/html` which I'm pretty sure would be taken care of at the `if var jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {` line anyways

Comment: But what *is* the data, did you verify that it's valid JSON? If yes, do what I suggested in my first comment. If no, fix this.